# is there a way to figure out how the disk space is getting used

Tags: disk-usage

If I use the `df -k -h` command, I can see that 181G are getting used
on my `/dev/sda3`.

But when I do `du -s -h /home`, I only get 40G as the return value. 
So, is there a method to figure out where the other 141G are getting used. Thanks a lot. Oh, I have the 1000 commands book but I can't find any good
commands for what I'm try to accomplish.

Output of command is below.

```
$ df -k -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev

tmpfs           787M   18M  770M   3% /run

/dev/sda3       440G  181G  237G  44% /

tmpfs           3.9G   38M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock

tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/sda1       496M   26M  471M   6% /boot/efi

cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs

tmpfs           787M  112K  787M   1% /run/user/1001

/dev/sdc1       932G  114G  819G  13% /media/markleeds/My Passport
```

Comment: Is `/dev/sda3` separate home partition ?

Comment: @Johnny: I edited the question so that it shows the output of df -k -h. But I do anything as far as creating my own parititions if that's the question ? Whatever the system was when I first booted, is what it still is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you execute the command on your `/home` folder, so the `du` only recognizes disk usage within `/home`, you have to specify the whole root partition. Try something like:

```
sudo du -sch * /
```

Will list total size of `/` (root) directory, now you should be able to see where the 141 GB remaining size.